# Responsive image slider bxslider only works on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, bxslider

I want to use the responsive image slider 'bxslider' (bxslider.com) on my site. Unfortunately the slider's images often don't appear on the page and only the controls are visible. However as soon as I refresh the page, the slider's images reappear.

I've looked at similar questions asked here, but he suggestions given - such as "only use jQuery 1.x" - don't seem to work for me.

Would be great if someone had another suggestion! The actual URL is: http://www.lauraniebel.com/casestudy01.htm and http://www.lauraniebel.com/casestudy02.htm And here's my code:

```
    <script src="js/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>


    <div class="bxslider3">    
            <img src="img/cvnewsletters01.jpg" alt="Curtin Volunteers Newsletters">
            <img src="img/cvnewsletters02.jpg" alt="Curtin Volunteers Newsletters">
        </div>

<div class="bxslider">    
            <img src="img/cvinfographic01.jpg" alt="Curtin Volunteers Infographic">
            <img src="img/cvinfographic02.jpg" alt="Curtin Volunteers Infographic Closeup">
        </div>

<div class="bxslider2">    
            <img src="img/cvposters01.jpg" alt="Curtin Volunteers Posters">
            <img src="img/cvposters02.jpg" alt="Curtin Volunteers Posters">
        </div>


<script>
      $( document ).ready(function(){
      $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    });

      $( document ).ready(function(){
      $('.bxslider2').bxSlider();
    });


     $( document ).ready(function(){
      $('.bxslider3').bxSlider();
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your images inside of a container, and give that container an explicit width and height.

Or set bxslider to load after the images have loaded, possibly using [image onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/image.onload)

As it stands, bxslider is initializing before the images have had time to load, calculating 0 width and height for them, thus giving them no appearance.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z3txd2bs/)

I've wrapped your images in a `<div class="container"></div>`, given that explicit width/height. The issue is inline elements (the images) calculating width/height based on their contents (the images that haven't loaded) and bxslider uses the 0 width/height to initialize itself.

Answer (score 0):

Typical jQuery problem. 
JavaScript is all like "You images done yet or what?"
Found this little plugin...
It detects when all the images have been properly rendered before the scr

[Github link](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)

CDN:

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<!-- or -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.js"></script>`